# Do you have a Geometry3D object representing an artificial satellite?

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data

Similar to the Mathematica command:

```
 ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]
```

Do you have something similar to that generates an artificial satellite (a craft that orbits Earth)?

Comment: I don't believe there are any in the example data (or in `SatelliteData`), but I was able to download a .obj file from [this site](https://free3d.com/3d-model/small-satellite-308237.html) for free, and import it:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwDlj.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically there are none built-in to the Wolfram Language, but you can import many of the models from the official [*NASA 3D Resources* github repository](https://github.com/nasa/NASA-3D-Resources/tree/master/3D%20Models).

```
Import["https://github.com/nasa/NASA-3D-Resources/blob/master/3D%20Models/Landsat%208%20(LDCM)/LDCM-2014-composite.lwo?raw=true"]
```

For instance, here's a Landsat model:

[image]

(use the "view raw" link for pasting into an `Import` command, or download the file.)